# Evaluate $\iiint(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})dxdydz$ for the positive octant, $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=9$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

Evaluate $\displaystyle\iiint(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})dxdydz$ for the positive octant, $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=9$.

This question needs to be solved in spherical coordinates. I tried putting a limit of $r$ from $0$ to $3$, $\theta$ from $0$ to $\pi/2$ and $\varphi$ from $0$ to $\pi/2$.

But What about $dxdydz$?

Answer (score 1):

Use $dxdydz=r^2dr\sin\theta d\theta d\phi$ (proven [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Example_3:_spherical-Cartesian_transformation)) so your integral is $$\frac18\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^\pi\sin\theta d\theta\int_0^3r^4dr=\frac182\pi2\frac{3^5}{5}=\frac{243\pi}{10}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The region projects to the quarter-circle $x^2+y^2\le 9$, $x,y\ge 0$, in the $xy$-plane, and so the triple integral in cartesian coordinates, yucky though it be, is
$$\int_0^3\int_0^{\sqrt{9-x^2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}}(x^2+y^2+z^2)dz\,dy\,dx.$$
You can actually evaluate this with some trigonometric substitutions, but, ultimately, spherical coordinates is the way to go.

Comment: The OP *wanted* to do it with spherical coordinates; the question was about how to rewrite $dxdydz$.

Comment: The question was confusing, as the OP knew the limits in spherical coordinates. But you're probably right. In addition, we never know if the spherical coordinates are European, physicists', or American mathematicians', so perhaps $\varphi$ is $\theta$ or perhaps not.